# Laravel group by adding multiple columns issue

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I get the following error when selecting more than one column in the query. I tried many ways but couldn't find a way. I am using the database PostgreSQL. How can I solve this problem?

> SQLSTATE[42803]: Grouping error: 7 ERROR:  column "sales_order.id"
> must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate
> function\nLINE

It gives an error when I add the following query.

```
select('name', 'category_id')
```

```
$categoryTotalSales = Sales::select('name', 'category_id')
    ->selectRaw('count (category_id) as total')
    ->orderBy("total", "desc")
    ->groupBy("category_id")
    ->orderBy('total', 'DESC')
    ->limit(5)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel does not allow group operation, so first you can allow the group operation.

**GO TO => Config => database.php file and change strict=false**

So after that, you can perform a group query.

Comment: I am not using mysql. I am using PostgreSql. I added `'strict' => false` but it didn't work.